# Return JSON via MVC controller vs webmethod

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, webmethod, jsonresult

I'm trying to convert a web forms page with a number of code-behind `webmethod` functions into an MVC view with a controller.

The data I get back is different. They have properly formatted JSON, but the webmethod returns JSON like this:

```
{"d":"{\"Success\":true,\"Data\":{\"QuoteId\":340439,\"LoginId\":40,
```

And the controller returns:

```
"{\"QuoteId\":340444,\"LoginId\":40,
```

Its not wrapping it in `data.d` like it is set up to handle in the javascript and there are no `Success` or `Data` objects. And when I try to parse it (`$.parseJSON(data)`) like I did with the `webmethod`, it gives me the old error at line 1 message.

I'm sure that if I played with it enough I could get it to work with the way the data is coming through, but I have many pages that I need to covert in the future and I'm just wondering if there is an easy way to get the controller to format it like the `webmethod` does.

I'm pretty sure that I know why the data is formatted differently, but it would make my life easier if I could just return the data in the same way. I've tried returning a `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)`, which is just a string, and a `Return Json(obj)`, which I'm guessing is just a string as well, but they both return stuff the same, non-data.d way.

Comment: So why not create a new object to wrap your responses if you want it to return the same JSON it was returning before? `public class JsonResponseWrapper { public bool Success {get; set;} public object Data {get;  set;} }` something along those lines.

Comment: @mason I've been trying that, but for some reason it just doesn't format the data the same. I can get it to essentially "look" the same, but it throws errors down the line in the JS where the webmethod doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've decided to wrap the data in a "d", so that I can have a "data.d" in the Ajax result.

But for some reason the dates aren't being formatted correctly when I just send the data back via:

```
return Json(thewrappeddata);
```

they turn out weird.

So basically what I have to do is this:

```
public class JSONReturn {
    public object d;
    public static object Wrap(object data) {
        return new JSONReturn() { d = data };
    }
}

var thedata = new TonsofData();

return Json(
    JSONReturn.Wrap(
       JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thedata, 
           new JsonSerializerSettings { 
              ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore 
           }
       )
   )
);
```

It seems like I'm "jsonifying" the data twice here, once with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` and once with `Json()` (I THINK that serializes), but it seems to work and now I get what I need and all the JS just works as it did before. If I leave out the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`, the `Json()` formats the dates incorrectly and it causes all sorts of failure down the line.